# Post-build event fails in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: c#, cruisecontrol.net, post-build-event

Using CC.net with Visual Studio 2012. CC.Netbuilds a C# project with a post-build event:

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)Instruments\$(OutDir)*.*" "$(TargetDir)" /d
```

It succeeds in Visual Studio. It fails in CC.Net. This is this error code:

> The command "copy "..\..\Instruments\bin\Release\*.*" "W:\Checkout\TeraSoft 1.0\Terasoft\Terasoft\bin\Release\" /d" exited with code 1. [W:\Checkout\TeraSoft 1.0\Terasoft\Terasoft\Terasoft.csproj]

The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) says error code 1 means "No files were found to copy." But there are numerous files in ..\..\Instruments\bin\Release. I read that error code 1 could also mean that it couldn't find the directory, but if Visual Studio can, then why not CC.Net?

CC.Net successfully builds the project if there is no post-build event. Any ideas about what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the Cruise Control service runs as a different user. It may be "Local System" or Network Service. 
I'm guessing that W: is not mapped for that user. If that's not it then the user probably doesn't have permission to that folder.

I also saw that the command `"copy "..\..\Instruments\bin\Release*.*"`
 is missing a backslash before the `"*.*"`

Comment: Sounds promising. I will try it tomorrow. The \ was exited by SO markup interpreter. Fixed it thanks